# Word VBA How to find and replace a string starting with "<start>" and ending with "<end>"?

Tags: vba, ms-word

As per the question, trying to replace a span of text in a Word document that is of the form

`"<start>..........<end>"`

of variable length. It will only occur once in the document.

Comment: And how do you want to do this? I assume you want to use a macro or vba function (since you did add the tag) but can you elaborate a bit? Do you want a textbox pop up to fill in the new text to be filled in? Or is this always the same text? And does the <start> and <end> tag also need to be replaced? If you add more detail to your question, the answer will become easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Word's built-in find/replace functionality to do this, eg

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
   .Text = "\<start\>*\<end\>"
   .Replacement.Text = ""
   .Forward = True
   .Format = False
   .MatchCase = False
   .MatchWholeWord = False
   .MatchWildcards = True
   .MatchSoundsLike = False
   .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

This was found from simply recording a macro with Word 2007 and viewing the VBA code. The `.Text` property can use wildcards, such as `*` and `[A-Z]`, similar to regular expressions referred to in @Jayantha's response. The back-slashes are included in the `.Text` property because `<` and `>` are wildcard characters too, and the back-slash escapes them. Search for "replace" in the Word help files.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know about the option for wildcards

Comment: Will this also find occurrences in headers and footers?

Comment: @Harikawashi not sure - you would have to try it

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions, try this:

```
/start\\.*/end\
```

Replace `/` with `<` and `\` with `>` in the above regex.

Comment: Be careful: in a string "[start]aa[end]bb[start]cc[end]", the *whole* text is matched, *including* that "bb".

Comment: @HansKesting: Not so, because Word uses "lazy" matching (matching as little as possible) rather than the more-common "greedy" matching found elsewhere. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regular expressions, you'll need to go to `Tools|References` and add `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions Libarary`

I think you could use `^<start>.*<end>$` for your regex.

This should be a comment to @Jayantha's answer probably, but not enough rep here.