# VBA word macro / automatically find and replace specific characters for whole document

Tags: vba, ms-word, character

I'm trying to do the following using the macro:
Upon opening the document, automatically search whole document for brackets `{{ }}` and delete them including the text inside.
It doesn't do the job well, just operates on the text selected, not the whole document.

```
Sub SelectToBracketsDelete()
  With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "{{"
    .Forward = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute
  End With
  Selection.Extend
  With Selection.Find
    .Text = "}}"
    .Forward = True
    .Execute
    .Text = ""
  End With
  Selection.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

Word 2007 -> [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191176/word-vba-how-to-find-and-replace-a-string-starting-with-start-and-ending-wit)

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
   .Text = "\{\{*\}\}"
   .Replacement.Text = ""
   .Forward = True
   .Format = False
   .MatchCase = False
   .MatchWholeWord = False
   .MatchWildcards = True
   .MatchSoundsLike = False
   .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```